# Add function that is called on each request in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1

I need to add a function in Symfony2 that has to be called on each request. (language detection on requestion & session)

I thought to do this in the constructor of my Controller classes, but there the container is not known / created.

Have you suggestions for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a listener that redirects to a page with the language set in the user configuration. Adapt it to your needs.

```
<?php
namespace MyVendor\Listener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;
use JMS\DiExtraBundle\Annotation\Service;
use JMS\DiExtraBundle\Annotation\InjectParams;
use JMS\DiExtraBundle\Annotation\Observe;

/**
 * @Service
 */
class LanguageListener
{
    /**
     * @var \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface
     */
    private $securityContext;

    /**
     * @var \Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface
     */
    private $router;

    /**
     * @InjectParams
     *
     * @param \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface $securityContext
     * @param \Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface $router
     */
    public function __construct(
        SecurityContextInterface $securityContext, 
        RouterInterface $router
    ) {
        $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
        $this->router          = $router;
    }

    /**
     * @Observe("kernel.request")
     *
     * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent $event
     */
    public function forceLanguage(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        if (HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST !== $event->getRequestType()) {
            return;
        }

        $token = $this->securityContext->getToken();

        if (!$token) {
            return;
        }

        if (!$this->securityContext->isGranted('ROLE_USER')) {
            return;
        }

        /** @var $request \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request */
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        $locale  = $request->getLocale();
        $route   = $request->get('_route');

        if ('_' === $route[0]) {
            return;
        }

        /** @var $user \MyVendor\Model\User */
        $user = $token->getUser();

        if ($user->getConfig()->getLanguage() !== $locale) {
            $parameters = array_merge($request->attributes->get('_route_params'), [
                '_locale' => $user->getConfig()->getLanguage(),
            ]);

            $path = $this->router->generate($route, $parameters);
            $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($path));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can define your Event Listener

Please, read documentation about [event listeners](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html) creation.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it depends on what you are trying to do. For language detection most of the time symfony and its bundles handle virtually everything. That means that if you want to customize the routing you have to extend the routing component by using `routing.loader` tag..
However if you can use [event listeners](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html) but I am not sure how many stuff you can change from there.

Answer (score 0):

Either use events as suggested above or if you need something quick.

You can override `setContainer` method.

```
namespace My\Namespace;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class MyController extends Controller 
{
    private $foo;

    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
    {
        parent::setContainer($container);
        $this->foo = 'bar';
    }
    // your actions
}
```